# ActionFilterAttribute and ExceptionFilterAttribute as one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, filtering

Is there any easy way to put those two filter attributes into one single attribute? Well multi-inheritance is not an option in C#. And interfaces does not seem to be any help here.

In another words i want to create single attribute who will provide both Action Filtering and Exception Filtering.

Comment: OK, but why do you want to do that?

Comment: I am using entity framework and wanna provide transaction rollback mechanism for errors in controller.


So transaction could be set up in OnActionExecting
and commited + disposed in OnActionExecuted (becouse entering it means no Exceptions were thrown) 

And if any exceptions were thrown i would rollback + dipose it in exception filter.

Becouse all those actions provide one functionality (database transaction support) i wanna use one attribute (not 2) to be able to provide it.

Comment: Then use a `TransactionScope`. If you don't commit it explicitly it rolls back when it goes out of scope or when you dispose it.

Comment: Yea but in my project ninject is used for providing most of things (including DbContext). Thats why i wanna do it like DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction.

Without exception filter transaction can be never disposed.

Comment: anyway, you shouldn't work with your database at the controller level, normally you would want to extract all that functionality and place it in a `Data Access Layer (DAL)`, which ideally would be accessed via an interface, this way your code would be a lot more testable. Your DAL should be responsible for your transactions, not your controller.

Comment: Well all other functionality for Database is in the Repository Layer. The problem is Ninject will provide one instance of DbContext per web request. Whathever transaction should be commited or not depends from success or fail of controller action. Besides i don't wanna put every action into transaction (GETs for example)

So i would really appreciate any other ideas for doing this.

Btw: Ofc i can warp DbContext thus Transaction into UnitOfWork but it does not change the fact that exception of action exection should be handled in ExceptionFilter.

Comment: But if u think this is a wrong way how would u implement rollback machanism per web request.

What i want from it is to commit when action succeed and rollback when it fails (exception is thrown).

And i wanna easy way for describing whatever controller or it's action should use this mechanism or not. Because Custom Action and Exception Filter Attributes seems great. The only downside is that i have to use 2 attributes instead of one.